# How to pass avalue from Thymeleaf to the Ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this table iterating through a list of logs. I want to do an ajax call so when a specific row is clicked, it takes the id of the log clicked and grabs that log's specific details/information, and inserts the information into a modal. I need help with two things, one - due to it being a dynamic url, I am getting unicode in the url instead of the actual id. I tried adding the [[ ]] around the log.id, but that's not working. My second issue is I'm not even sure I am sending the log id to the ajax call. Could someone please let me know if I'm on the right track, or  how to get rid of the unicode and convert the id in the url ?

```html
<table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-search="true"  data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>When</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th class="text-right"><a class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a></th>
            <th class="text-right"><a class="trigger btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <tr th:each="log : ${logs}">
              <td th:if="${log.time!=null}" th:text="${{#temporals.format(log.time,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a')}}"></td>
              <td th:text="${log.subject}"></td>
              <td style="white-space: pre-wrap;" th:text="${log.notes}"></td>
              <td class="text-right"><a th:value="${log}" class="trigger-edit-log"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a></td>
              <td class="text-right"><a th:href="@{|/delete/callLog/${log.id}|}"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Ajax call inside the document ready function:

```html
        $(document).on('click', '.trigger-edit-log', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log($('a').attr('id'));
              $.ajax({
                 url:"/callLogs/${{callLog.id}}",
                 data: "id="+ $('a').attr('id'),
                 success: function(data){
                     $('#editLog').append(data);
                     $('#editLog').html(data);
                     $('#modal-edit-log').iziModal('open');
                 }
              });
        });
```

```html
    @RequestMapping(value = "/callLog/{id}")
    public String task(@PathVariable("id")CallLog callLog, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("callLog",callLog);
        return "redirect:/callLogs/client/" + callLog.getClient().getId();
    }
```

Comment: what is `callLog.id` ?

Comment: Not sure if I should use callLog as it is the official name of the model/class, or if I should use log.id, as log is only formed in the th:each loop...

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your problem. Based on what I understand I am trying to answer.

You can use `th:data` on your `td` and set value of `CallLog.id` there.

```
<td class="text-right"><a th:value="${log}"  th:data-calllogid= ="${CallLog.id}"class="trigger-edit-log"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a></td>
```

Now on your javascript you can get this value as below.

```
$(event.relatedTarget).data("calllogid");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change the row on your code:

```html
<td class="text-right"><a th:value="${log}" class="trigger-edit-log"><span class="fa fa- pencil"></span></a></td>
```

With the following one:

```html
<td class="text-right"><a href="#" class="trigger-edit-log" th:data-logId="${log.id}" onclick="getLogDetailsForId(this.getAttribute('data-logId'));"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a></td>
```

And try this javascript:

```js
function getLogDetailsForId(logId) {
 $.ajax({
    url:"/callLogs/" + logId,
    success: function(result){
     $('#editLog').append(result);
     $('#editLog').html(result);
     $('#modal-edit-log').iziModal('open');
 }});
}
```

PS Try it and check that the URL is the correct one /callLogs/ etc.
Also check if you need post/get ETC...

So you change the html/thymeleaf to pass in the log id into the javascript function, getLogDetailsForId(....) and that's the place that you make your ajax call.

Once you get it working I'm sure you can clean it up...

Comment: See this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224058/org-thymeleaf-exceptions-templateprocessingexception-only-variable-expressions