# Thymeleaf: Only variable expressions returning numbers or booleans are allowed in this context

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE RESTful Web Service app., using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this piece of code in one of my templates,

```
<tr th:each="menuPriceSummary: ${menus}" >  

...

    <a href="#" th:onclick="|changeAIColor('idAwesomeIconFAV${menuPriceSummary.menu.symbol}');| + 'performAjaxCall(\'' + @{/allmenupricesummary/switchfav/{id}(id=${menuPriceSummary.menu.symbol})} + '\');'" >              
        <span th:if="${menuPriceSummary.favorited}">
            <i th:id="'idAwesomeIconFAV'+${menuPriceSummary.menu.symbol}"  class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-lg" style="color:#009900; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <span th:if="${!menuPriceSummary.favorited}">
            <i th:id="'idAwesomeIconFAV'+${menuPriceSummary.menu.symbol}" class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg"  style="color:#e6e6e6;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </a>
</tr>
```

But I got this error when rendering the template:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Only variable expressions returning numbers or booleans are allowed in this context, any other datatypes are not trusted in the context of this expression, including Strings or any other object that could be rendered as a text literal. A typical case is HTML attributes for event handlers (e.g. "onload"), in which textual data from variables should better be output to "data-*" attributes and then read from the event handler.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Only variable expressions returning numbers or booleans are allowed in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224058/org-thymeleaf-exceptions-templateprocessingexception-only-variable-expressions)

Comment: I had same question few months back. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224058/org-thymeleaf-exceptions-templateprocessingexception-only-variable-expressions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to move your Thymeleaf expressions to `th:data-*` attributes, and use `this.getAttribute('...')` instead.  Something like this for example:

```
<tr th:each="menuPriceSummary: ${menus}" >  
    <a  href="#"
        th:data-icon="|idAwesomeIconFAV${menuPriceSummary.menu.symbol}|"
        th:data-url="@{/allmenupricesummary/switchfav/{id}(id=${menuPriceSummary.menu.symbol})}"
        onclick="changeAIColor(this.getAttribute('data-icon')); performAjaxCall(this.getAttribute('data-url'));">
        <span th:if="${menuPriceSummary.favorited}">
            <i th:id="'idAwesomeIconFAV'+${menuPriceSummary.menu.symbol}"  class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-lg" style="color:#009900; text-align: center;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>

        <span th:if="${!menuPriceSummary.favorited}">
            <i th:id="'idAwesomeIconFAV'+${menuPriceSummary.menu.symbol}" class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg"  style="color:#e6e6e6;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </a>
</tr>
```

Comment: I know this solution, but what is mean of 'this' (its type) in this context?because intellij IDEA gives me 'Cannot resolve' and I want to add thymesVar id/type for it.

Comment: Are you using `th:onclick` instead of `onclick`?  `this` is referring to the javascript dom element of the `<a />` tag (and shouldn't have anything to do with Thymeleaf).

Comment: I agree. But I don't know why the intellij IDEA shows an error hint and says "can not resolve this'.

Answer (score 5):

You can use like bellow

```
<div th:each="file: ${files}">
   <input type="button"  th:data-parameter1="${file.id}"  th:data-parameter2="${file.name}  th:onclick="passValue(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1'),this.getAttribute('data-parameter2'))" />
</div>
```

In javaScript user

```
function test(id,name){
        
    }
```