# How to call JavaScript function from Thymeleaf-style-background?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have a table with cells and want to move background settings for each cell to JavaScript. How to do it?
For now I can't reach function color1

```html
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function color1(row, col){
          if(isOdd(row) && isOdd(col)) return "#f4cd8d";
          if(isEven(row) && isEven(col)) return "#745853";
        }    
        
        function isEven(n) {
           return n % 2 == 0;
        }
        
        function isOdd(n) {
           return Math.abs(n % 2) == 1;
        }  
    </script>       

</head>
<body>  

<table id="chessboard" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr height="30"
        th:each="row, rStat : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}">
        <td width="30"  th:each="col, cStat : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}"            
            th:data-row=${rStat.count} 
            th:data-col=${cStat.count}             
            th:style="'background: onload="javascript:color1(${rStat.count},${cStat.count})";'"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Take a look at the technique used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55765317/12567365) - especially `onclick="changeAIColor(this.getAttribute('data-icon'));"`. You are using `onload` not `onclick` - but the technique is the same.

Comment: Alternatively, in your case, it may be easier to do what you want by using your script to iterate over the entire table and assign background colors from the script rather than passing values from the HTML to the script. That way you would not need any `background` settings in your Thymeleaf HTML. JavaScript would take care of that.

Comment: no, this is not the way for me. After the table I have "script", which onclick (addEventListener) sends data to Controller (Spring). (system does not let to insert full code) So, the full logic: chess board drawn, onclick it transfers to Controller as $post (jQuery), made calculations in Controller and brings back the page with some data. I want to send this data in javascript and return back 1 out of 4 possible colors for my background. So for sure I want be able to work out my logic in javascrip.

Comment: Understood - it may be worth editing your question to include those clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

try calling JavaScript like this:

```
<table id="chessboard" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr height="30"
    th:each="row, rStat : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}">
    <td th:id="${id}" width="30"  th:each="col, cStat : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}"            
        th:data-row=${rStat.count} 
        th:data-col=${cStat.count}             
        th:attr="onload='color1(${rStat.count},${cStat.count})'"> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and in javascript you can set the style of the field

```
function color1(row, col){
    var cell = document.querySelector('#id');
    var color;
    if(isOdd(row) && isOdd(col)) color = "#f4cd8d";
    if(isEven(row) && isEven(col)) color = "#745853";
    cell.style.background = color;
}
```

Comment: Feels like it still does not launch function color1

Comment: did you enter any id or class to identify the cell? try inspecting the page to see what the html tag looks like.

Comment: try this with `|` :

`th:attr="|onload='color1(${rStat.count},${cStat.count})'|"`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using JQuery, why not use the document.ready() to assign colors like this?  No need for any JavaScript on the table itself.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.chessboard-square').each(function () {
    let row = parseInt($(this).data('row'));
    let col = parseInt($(this).data('col'));
    $(this).css('background-color', color1(row, col));
  })
});
</script>

<!-- Table -->
<table id="chessboard" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr height="30" th:each="row, rStat : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}">
    <td class="chessboard-square" width="30" th:each="col, cStat : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}"
        th:data-row="${rStat.count}"
        th:data-col="${cStat.count}">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the ($post) is only thing I've learned today about jQuery. Will try to figure out what you've wrote. For now it gives an error on line (let row = parseInt...)

Comment: [I tested it locally and it worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP9q6.png), so not sure what error you could be be getting.