# Thymeleaf onclick send string as parameter value to javascript function

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to pass multiple parameters on onClick in From Thymeleaf to javascript function.

```
<label th:onclick="getUserId(userId,email);" for="radio-11" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover"  class="pm-tab1-pad">
```

My Javascript function is:-

```
<script>
   function getUserId(userID,userEmail){
      console.log(userID,userEmail);
    }
</script>
```

How to do it?

Comment: have you checked your label is clicked without passing any parameters?
try doing in this way `<ELEMENT onclick="handler">`

Comment: Yes, i have checked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done by using the following:-

```
<label th:onclick="getUserId([[${userId}]],[[${email}]] );" for="radio-11" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover"  class="pm-tab1-pad">
```

Here, userId is of Integer type end email is of String type.

Update :-

This also works:-

```
<label th:data-parameter1="${userId}" th:data-parameter2="${email}"  th:onclick="getUserId(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1'),this.getAttribute('data-parameter2'));" for="radio-11" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover"  class="pm-tab1-pad">
```

Comment: This will not work going forward. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224058/org-thymeleaf-exceptions-templateprocessingexception-only-variable-expressions

Comment: I have updated the answer, but you downvoted my earlier answer,was my answer wrong ?